# AWS SNS, Apple Push Services, I get invalid platform credentials errors even after renewing certs and uploading associated .p12 creds

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm running into an issue where I'm seeing delivery failures to iOS endpoints only with the "Platform application credentials are not valid" error.  This is for our app that's been in the app store for years.  I've cleaned out all my certs, renewed them, uploaded them, and updated my AWS SNS platform creds to the new .p12 file .  I have double confirmed all the certs expire 1 year from now. I've also confirmed that I created certs for production level push notifications and app distribution.

This week, I managed to get push notifications working twice.  On Day 1, I go through the renewing certs, etc., test push notifications on a variety of iphones, then wait until the next day and notice delivery failures due to bad platform credentials.  On Day 2, I go through the same steps to the point where push notifications are working again.  Then, the next day I see delivery failures due to the same reason. After that happens the platform is disabled and push notifications fail to be delivered.

In both cases, something has happened overnight that causes AWS SNS to think the APNS certs are invalid. Has someone experienced the same thing?

Thanks for your help!

dzincolorado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my APS certificate wasn't the correct one.  After revoking it and using the correct .certSigningRequest file, I re-downloaded the .cer file, double clicked it and noticed that it created a new item in Keychain Access 'My Certificates' section.  Removing the other APS certs and using this new one, I exported it as a .p12 and updated my AWS SNS creds and it's now working.

Edit: Using a bad cert, it is odd that notifications worked for about a day before they started failing.

Thanks.